# Drupal 7.x duplicate file js ?? Why?

Tags: 7, javascript, css-js-aggregation

I don't know beacuse drupal duplicate one of my javascript files...

So:

I had added file "Intro.js" with template.php.
I wrote:

```
if(drupal_is_front_page()){
  drupal_add_js(path_to_theme() . '/scripts/Intro.js');
}
```

In the front page I wrote the call for that file.js

For optimize the web site I have "[Advagg module](https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg)"
If I analyze my web site with Pingdom tools i see that there are two files "Intro.js":

Intro.js

Intro.js?ni7wan

BUT i think that the part after "?" change when the cron ran. Is there a solution to delete the duplicate?

Comment: Is this file mentioned in your theme info file, or sth like that?

Comment: @Molot no, that isn't mentonied in the info theme file... Do you think that this is the problem??? But for example i had added another file.js in the template file (but is added for all pages, not only for front-page and it isn't mentonied in info file) and it is not duplicate..

Comment: Trying using the `#attach` property in the relevant renderable array. God forbids calling drupal_add_js in any D7+ site.

Comment: #attach where? :(

Comment: Nothing ??? Help me :(